# How to access json data in querybuilder parser for laravel?

Tags: php, json, laravel

I am a novice developer and I am stuck here since last few days. I am using jQuery query builder parser for laravel by timgws and sending the form data by Ajax. I can get the query in the controller but I want to access the JSON data before making the query. I was following this [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29308898/how-do-i-extract-data-from-json-with-php) but i can't access the data even after `json_decode()` with "true" argument. Here is the data I receive in the controller:

```
{
  "condition": "AND",
  "rules": [
    {
      "id": "diseases",
      "field": "mesh_id",
      "type": "string",
      "input": "select",
      "operator": "equal",
      "value": "C535575"
    }
  ],
  "valid": true
}
```

How can I access this value/type/fields from this data?

Comment: Can you print your Request Data and post here.

Comment: {condition: "AND", rules: Array(1), valid: true}condition: "AND"
rules: Array(1)0:field: "mesh_id"
id: "diseases"
input: "select"
operator: "equal"
type: "string"
value: "C535575"
__proto__: Object
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
valid: true
__proto__: Object